# In VB how do you print the first letter of a string

Tags: vb.net, loops

I have a string that contains "Havana"

**Question:** How do I print the first letter "H" (by using a loop)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substring() returns a new String instance containing the range of characters. It throws Exceptions on invalid arguments.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim literal As String = "Havana"

        ' Take the first 3 characters and put them in a new string.
        Dim substring As String = literal.Substring(0, 1)
        Console.WriteLine("SUBSTRING: {0}", substring)
    End Sub

End Module
```

> Output
>
> SUBSTRING: H

Comment: You could also just do `Console.WriteLine(literal[0]);`

Comment: @ChrisDunaway This is a vb.net question. Not to confuse a newby. `Console.WriteLine(listeral(0))`

Comment: @Mary - Oops!  My mistake.  I program primarily in C#.  I guess I just posted on "autopilot".  Thanks for catching that.